# Tuning fork quality factor measurement using SR 830 lock-in amplifier

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-transport

I've read about some methods based on SR 830 to conduct measurement on tuning fork Q, such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.01584. But I am wondering can I use the sine output signal directly as excitation source instead of using an independent function generator as the excitation source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Directly use the sine wave as the excitation voltage, and measure from $A$, there would be a peak around the resonance peak frequency $f_0$.

Comment: f0 is the resonance peak frequency.